# Dexie js with Cordova sqlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, dexie

I know dexie js works with indexedDB.  But in Cordova app, SQLite offers more storage, fewer limitations.

Are there adapters for dexie for this?

If not, are there some good query wrappers for in-browser indexedb, and on mobile use sqlite.

Mike

Comment: Im also looking at livefield, forerunnerdb if they support sqlite, it would also work.